# firebase push notifications crashes my App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

i am using Firebase push notifications but when i make a message from the Firebase console ! my app crashes ? and here is the error occurred
[image]

Note : i have two previous applications working with Firebase push notifications and they works good !

Comment: Is it always or some devices only? If some devices only, check if they have installed google play services.

Comment: i have another application on the same device and the process works good with it . 
but it does not work with this specific application.

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200664/firebase-messaging-nosuchmethoderror-zzur-exception, and see if it works.