# error with gcm while generating signed apk android

Tags: java, android, apk

I got an error while generating signed apk in android studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':AppName:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzv$zza$zza.class
```

Gradle....

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myApp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.1.4'
    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/mint-4.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: add this line to dependency..compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])..and add the jar files to dependency..and sync the proj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different versions of play services.this usually ends up in error.change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38201741/3111083.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of duplicate or transitive dependencies in your gradle. To check where the duplication is arising from, always construct the dependency tree first.

This is done via the `allDependencies` gradle task. On the right hand bar in your Android Studio, click Gradle > app > Tasks > Android > androidDependencies. Your gradle console will now have your dependency tree outputted in the form of

```
|    +--- pm.tin.tincan.android:sectioned-recyclerview:1.0
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.4
|    |    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
|    |    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.1
|    |    |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.3
|    |    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
|    |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.1
|    |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    +--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0
```

Here, check for conflicting library versions everywhere in your tree.
Once that's sorted, you can exclude conflicting deps by saying

```
compile("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1") {
            transitive = true
            exclude group: "com.android.support" // Conflicting dep removed here
        }
```