# Problems updating PlayServices/Firebase from 10.0.1 to 10.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am developing an android app using Android Studio and got the message today that there is a new version of Google Play services.

I am using Google play services analytics, ads and tag manager. As well as Firebase analytics/messaging/crash.

The version I had in my build.gradle was 10.0.1 and the new version is 10.2.0
But when I change it, the app crashes on start with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sega.segaid, PID: 15749
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaac.zza
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcl(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4964)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:810)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this an error on my side? It crashes before the app even starts. The only thing I changed is updating the used dependencies of the play services and firebase.

The last time something like that happened, it was a bug in Firebase, which was fixed by Google after some days.

**EDIT**:
build.gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
```

**SOLUTION**:
I cleared all caches and also added the version as def instead if writing it out each time. It worked now. Thank you everyone.

I picked the answer by rencsaridogan as solution because I think I forgot to update one of the libraries at my first try and the def is really helpful there. But I also needed to clear caches (as recommended by Avi in the comments below).

Comment: Please add your gradle file . Also try cleaning and syncing the project.

Comment: try with clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Make sure your all Google play services and firebase version is "10.2.0" in gradle file.

Comment: Most probably related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200664/firebase-messaging-nosuchmethoderror-zzur-exception.

Comment: as said by Akash and sunil you need to update both, if error still exists then post gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 important things about Google Play Services and Firebase usage as stated in [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

You need to declare the latest classpath of Google Play Services in your **root-level gradle**, example quoted from given documentation:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Also, as comments suggest in your project every **Google Play Services** and **Firebase** package has to have same version, to ensure this you can follow the method given below (It'll be easier like this, you only need to update version number on definitions)

```
def googlePlayLibVersion = "10.2.0"
def googleFirebaseLibVersion = "10.2.0"

ext {
  annotations = "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
  firebaseAnalytics = "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${googleFirebaseLibVersion}"
  firebaseCrash = "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${googleFirebaseLibVersion}"
  googlePlayAds = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${googlePlayLibVersion}"
  googlePlayGcm = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${googlePlayLibVersion}"
  googlePlayAnalytics = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${googlePlayLibVersion}"
}
```

Comment: I have it included in my root level gradle. The def looks like a nice idea, i will try that one out.

Comment: @Cubicle257 happy to share! Hope this helps you.

Comment: While I also needed to clear the caches, I picked your answer as solution, because the def certainly proved helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Cubicle257, happy coding!