# Application crashed with NoSuchMethodError on startup while adding Firebase Library

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle

Received this error when application start and when i remove firebase compile library application run perfect but i want to use both library firebase and googlePlay services

```
05-25 14:02:43.525 22035-22035/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
05-25 14:02:43.525 22035-22035/? E/Zygote: v2
05-25 14:02:43.540 22035-22035/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable 
seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
05-25 14:02:44.795 22035-22035/com.totalsoft.hajjapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.totalsoft.hajjapp, PID: 22035
                                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx' appears in /data/app/com.totalsoft.hajjapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes35.dex)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1716)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1685)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5559)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5094)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

**Here is my build file i add firebase dependencies with googlePlay services**

```
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.totalsoft.hajjapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 19
    versionName "8.7.5"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    lintOptions {
      warning "InvalidPackage"
}
    }

 dependencies {
compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'

////
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0"

 }
```

`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
maven{
url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
   }
   }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
}


 allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try by not including google firebase library to proguard.

Comment: i am using android studio what i will do for this?

Comment: Keep the same versions for playservices and firebase. Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200664/firebase-messaging-nosuchmethoderror-zzur-exception

Answer (score 2):

Match Firebase and Google libraries to same version.

This 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.6' 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
And 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'

Comment: yes i change but it gives values-v24.xml error

Comment: this version (numbers) that i have provided as example are the latest versions of the library present. Either decrease versions to match your need (which is not got solution) or raise compile and target SDK (and update SDK libraries). That should update your app settings to compile correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing dependency versions that are interdependent:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0"
```

Dependency on play services:

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-    basement:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.1
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.1
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 -> 10.2.4 (*)
```

As can be seen above the firebase core dependency depends on the play services library. This causes a problem because one one library may be looking at version 10 whilst the compiled in version is actually 8.4 therefore methods can be missing, which is what the exception is telling you. (`No static method`)

The firebase libraries do depend on the `play-services` core library so please make sure they are compatible, this can be done by using the latest version numbers: `10.2.4`

You are also missing the the firebase core dependency, add: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'`

Comment: i used 
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'

 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1"

Comment: but error not resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to update your Google Play Service to the last version
```

I faced the same issue when I tried to use firebase-messaging:10.2.0 and to fix that I did this:

```
.On Android studio, go to the menu bar and click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
.Click on the SDK Tools tab
.check the Google Play services box as well as the Google Repository box.
.Click on apply, it will prompt you before applying the new updates.
.Click Ok and wait for the download
.Sync your project again and everything is fine
```

Note: All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). If you already have an existing dependency of google play services upgrade it to the same version as firebase.

Answer (score -1):

Put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`at the bottom of your `app/build.gradle`

Comment: yes i add but same error received

Comment: Erase from the top of the file

Comment: yes brother i erase and add it after the dependency(Bottom of the code)

Comment: what i should do now?

Comment: Use same version of firebase no appindexing:10.0.1 and database:9.8.0

Comment: yes i used but same error occour