# ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbtt.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbtt.class

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: Please make sure all Firebase and Google play services are the exact same version

Comment: I have attached a picture which show the dependencies i haves used

Comment: Your firebase and playservices are different versions. Make them the same versions. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200664/firebase-messaging-nosuchmethoderror-zzur-exception.

Comment: Add your Gradle file **as text**, please

Comment: It is resolved by changing the firebase versions same as google. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure all Firebase and Google play services are the exact same version (11.0.2, for example)
2. Refer to the FirebaseUi github for a table of the correct versions to use for Firebase 11.0.2
3. Unrelated, but your Volley library dependency is deprecated (see it's respective Github page). Similarly, you shouldn't need Volley if using Apache HTTP libraries

Answer (score 0):

This help me `./gradlew :app:dependencies`
and you will see all your dependencies like this:

```
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ -> 11.0.4
|  |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+ -> 11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ -> 11.8.0
```

and you have to find wrong versions. In my case it was `location:+ -> 11.8.0`
and i my fix it in `app/build.gradle` like this

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4') {
   force = true;
}
```