# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg.class

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am beginner in android, I try to run my app on real device but this error occur
I know that some file are duplicates, but I don't know how to fix it

This my build gradle
This my erorr

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg.class

This my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mohammed.fireapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

need help .

Comment: Makes sure that you're using the same library version for all of Firebase (and play services):

Comment: i tray but not working ?

Comment: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'

Comment: i already compile it in my gradle but this error above occur to me

Comment: error occur  when run my app to real device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905378/2360269