# eror : duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzasf$zza.class

Tags: android

I encounter the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzasf$zza.class

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/fastjson-1.2.5.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.3'
    compile files('universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    compile project(':Gpu-Image')
    compile project(':ImageViewTouch')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile project(':libAds')
    compile 'ir.sls.mono:Monolytics:+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':inAppPurchase')
    compile project(':inAppSDK')
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: probably onesignal is the library which is used to receive android notifications in your app and may be it uses FCM/GCM to solve this purpose. now as i can see that you too are using gcm library so whenever gradle imports both the library it finds that there is one common class in both the libraries. so you might need to exclude that class from either one signal or gcm to get it working. Also my suggestion would be to use FCM as gcm is now not in use anymore

Comment: Rihan husain tnx - What is the solution that is presented?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905378/2360269